# MatLab, How do I organize rows in ascending order but ignore zero values?

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, zero

If I have a matrix such as this:

```
A=[ 8 3 67 8 2 0 0 0 0 0; 8 76 9 233 1 89 34 0 0 0; 98 23 87 9 3 24 64 45 1 0]
```

and I use the command sort(A,2) it will sort alongside the columns but at the same time push the zeros forward. I would like to keep the 0's to the end for computing purposes later on in the code.

I I have been looking for a command that does this, as I feel there is one.
I have also generally been trying to sort, flip, and transpose to get what I want but Im at an impasse.

Comment: Alternative solutions and benchmarking is provided in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882130/sort-in-ascending-order-but-keep-zeros-at-last?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace the `0` by `Inf`, then sort and after the sort replace the `Inf` by `0` once again.

Comment: Does this mean I am replacing all numerical values of 0 with a string value? Wow, I wouldn't have thought of replacing the 0's with string. So what I end up doing is something like this A( A==0 )=Inf  and it works! Thanks!

Comment: `Inf` is not a string. It is a number representing infinity.