# Sort in ascending order, but keep zeros at last

Tags: matlab, sorting

Suppose I have a matrix `A`, on the following form.

```
A =
    35     1     6
     3    32     0
     0     9     0
     0     0     0
```

I want to sort it in ascending order, but keep the zeros at last.

I know I can subsitute all zeros with `inf`, sort it, and replace the `inf`s with zeros again, as proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871227/matlab-how-do-i-organize-rows-in-ascending-order-but-ignore-zero-values).

I would think there was a simpler way. At least since my zeros are already in the bottom rows. Can I do this in a single line?

What I want:

```
A =
     3     1     6
     35    9     0
     0     32    0
     0     0     0
```

Thanks!

## **UPDATE**

There was a question regarding the overhead of Eitan's answer. Here are the results (averaged, and after warm up):

```
B =  kron(A,ceil(rand(2000)*1000));  % 8000x6000 matrix
C = B;

%% Eitan's solution:
t1 = tic; B(B ~= 0) = nonzeros(sort(B)); toc(t1)
Elapsed time is  1.768782 seconds.

%% From question text:
B = C;
t1 = tic; B(B==0)=Inf; B = sort(B); B(B==Inf)=0; toc(t1) 
Elapsed time is 1.938374 seconds.

%% evading's solution (in the comments):
B = C;
t1 = tic; for i = 1:size(B,2)  index = B(:,i) ~= 0; B(index, i) = sort(B(index, i)); end
toc(t1)
Elapsed time is 1.954454 seconds.

%% Shai's solution (in the comments):
B = C;
t1 = tic; sel = B==0; B(sel)=inf;B=sort(B);B(sel)=0; toc(t1)
Elapsed time is 1.880054 seconds.
```

Comment: can you change all the "0" to a "max-value", then sort, in the end replace all "max-value" with "0"

Comment: @RoeeGavirel: I can... The question is: Can I avoid it? It seems a bit  cumbersome for such a simple task. I would need to do: `A(A==0) = Inf` first, and `A(A==Inf) = 0` in the end, thus search through the matrix twice for these values. (Needless to say, the matrices are a bit larger than 4x3) =)

Comment: are there no zeros mixed with the numbers?

Comment: @evading: No, all of them are in the end.

Comment: sort() takes a second argument which is a compare function.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - what??? are you talking of Matlab or `std::sort`?

Comment: Matlab. Though just about every language does something similar.

Comment: No being sure how matlab behaves under the hood i would think 
`for i = 1:size(A,2)
    index = A(:,i) ~= 0;
    A(index, i) = sort(A(index, i));
end` would only look for zeros once and then use direct indexing...

Comment: @RobertP. have you tired `sel = B==0; B(sel)=inf;B=sort(B);B(sel)=0;`?

Comment: Good thing I put the answer in the comments, since I obviously did not have a clue =)

Comment: @Shai. Thanks! I have now, and it works fine. Seems like Eitan's solution is a bit faster though.

Comment: @evading: Your solution works, so "not having a clue" is a bit harsh I think =)

Comment: I get different results. @Shai's is a good amount faster (`0.963290` sec.) than @Eitan's solution (`1.240851` sec.) - R2012a, OS X 10.8.3, Retina MacBook Pro. Some aspect of this is version/platform dependent. I'd blame `nonzeros`.

Comment: @horchler I suspect `nonzeros` builds upon sparse data, maybe there's a conversion in the background?

Comment: @horchler: I just double checked my results, and they don't change. I'm using R2013a, on a Win-8 machine. You're probably right regarding `nonzeros`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can guarantee that the zeros are only at the bottom of each column, you can do:

```
A(A ~= 0) = nonzeros(sort(A));
```

Comment: wont that give the same overhead as A(A==0) = Inf first, and A(A==Inf) = 0?? nonzeros finds all the non-zeros and A~=0 finds all the zeros.

Comment: I added the results of the two methods to the question. It looks like @Eitan's solution is a bit faster.